# « Comme ça » : Tic ou tact ?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques, locutions

On utilise « comme ça » pour faire référence à une manière de faire, et dans cet usage le pronom « ça » a un antécédent, c'est à dire un antécédent nominal ou bien un antécédent qui se construit à partir du contexte.

Cependant il existe une façon de terminer certaines assertions par « comme ça » qui ne remplit pas ce critère : « ça » ne remplace rien. C'est une façon de s'exprimer qui n'est pas trouvée chez les gens instruits, il me semble, et il me semble aussi qu'elle pourrait ne pas appartenir au français correct; cependant, je voudrais m'en assurer et je suis curieux de savoir, au cas où une signification aurait  été reconnue à ces mots, ou même si « ça » dans cette locution avait absolument toujours un antécédent constructible, quel sens aurait pu leur être donné.

Il me semble que cet ajout à la fin des phrases provient d'un automatisme irraisonné produit originellement par une forte exposition à des phrases où la locution a un sens clair.  Quelques exemples suivent ; on trouve cet usage dans des phrases négatives, des injonctions, autant que je puisse me rappeler ; il y a souvent une légère pause entre la locution et le reste de la phrase et on a toujours la nette impression que « ça » ne remplace rien.

On trouve aussi cet usage dans des questions dont le ton n'est pas nécessairement réprobatif.

- Mais arrête de mentir comme ça !
- Ne soit pas entêté comme ça, tu n'y gagnes rien…
- Ne vous mettez pas en colère comme ça !
- Pourquoi tu racontes ta vie à tout le monde comme ça ?

*Question*

Est-ce que cette locution, dans l'emploi cité — que je trouve sans fondement grammatical —  serait purement un [tic de langage](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic_de_langage) (aucune mention de cela dans la présente page web) ou bien cet emploi aurait-il finalement reçu la consécration d'un sens reconnu, par exemple en tant qu'atténuation de la force réprobatrice de l'énonciation ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117224/discussion-on-question-by-lph--comme-ca--tic-ou-tact).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Tic tac toc*](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17567334) ? Plus sérieusement, dans certains cas un complément peut préciser après coup alors que dans d'autres cas ça peut même être accompagné de gestes et il y a plusieurs cas où le sens est figé de sorte que l'on ne peut vraiment affirmer ce que l'on affirme d'entrée de jeu en question. Le critère de la position en fin de phrase ne semble pas davantage pertinent.

D'autre part on peut même l'employer de manière entièrement explétive ("Se dit d’un mot qui, sans être nécessaire au sens de la phrase ou sans être exigé par la syntaxe, sert parfois à marquer ou souligner une nuance. *Pronom explétif. Particule explétive*. *Dans « Goûtez-moi ce vin-là », « moi » est explétif.*") ([Ac.9](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9E3452)). Évidemment dans un tel cas la recherche de la valeur du pronom s'avère encore moins pertinente que précédemment.

Maintenant que l'on sait que le fait que ce soit grammatical ou non ne dépend pas de la détermination de la valeur du pronom, on peut reprendre une partie du propos d'une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/43923/25619), avec laquelle on est entièrement d'accord, à l'effet qu'avec un verbe c'est essentiellement « de cette manière, de cette façon, ainsi » (TLFi) et que c'est tout à fait courant. Plus généralement, les extraits suivants offriront des pistes de réflexion sur certains des différents emplois, leur richesse, leur harmonie et leur parfaite adéquation avec la langue française, ses auteurs et ses locuteurs.

---

TLFi, « [comme](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/comme) » :

[...]
**II**.− Morph. de compar. Dans ces emplois comme exprime une idée de similitude, l'écart avec l'idée d'identité pouvant être plus ou moins réduit selon le contexte.
**A**.− **Comme** + compl.
**1.** La compar. porte sur une ressemblance de manière.
[...]
**d)** **Comme** *cela/ça*
− Verbe + **comme** *cela*. *Comme cela*. De cette manière, de cette façon, ainsi (*cf*. *cela* I C 5 a).
− Subst. + **comme** *cela*. *Comme cela*. De cette espèce, de cette sorte (*cf*. aussi *cela* I C 5 a) :
18. Ceux qui sont dans la voiture, c'est la plupart du temps toujours les mêmes : un acheteur de lavande qui vient des villes de la côte, un camous, ou un nom **comme** *ça*; un berger qui monte aux pâtures, et qui taille régulièrement dans son pain un morceau pour lui, un morceau pour son chien; ... Giono, *Regain*, 1930, p. 11.
− [Dans la lang. parlée, *comme ça* peut s'accompagner d'un geste de locuteur qui simule la manière dont une chose a été faite] *Escartefigue. − Comment font-ils? Le Chauffeur. − Ils font comme ça. (Il fait des gestes véhéments et désordonnés)* (Pagnol, *Marius*, 1931, I, 1, p. 16):
19. Visios qui roulait son store, il m'interpelle tout exprès... Il me fait en passant **comme** *ça*... : « Dis-donc, ta mère, Ferdinand, elle est descendue au moins vingt fois depuis sept heures, demander si on t'a pas vu! ... » Céline, *Mort à crédit*, 1936, p. 383.
20. − Si longtemps, ma tante! Plus de huit ans que vous êtes partie; cinq ans que nous ne vous avons pas vue... − C'est vrai. Trois ans dans le Midi pour ma santé, deux ans de voyage à travers le monde. Karelina était haute **comme** *ça*! Quel âge a-t-elle maintenant? M. Van der Meersch, *L'Empreinte du dieu*, 1936, p. 12.
− *Comme ça* peut indiquer la manière désinvolte, facile, irréfléchie, insoupçonnée, dont une chose a été faite ou le ton d'indifférence dont une chose a été dite. Familier (*cf*. aussi cela I C 5 b). *La Bonne. − Madame m'a dit comme ça, que ces Messieurs veulent bien attendre* (T. Bernard, *M. Codomat*, 1907, I, 4, p. 144).− *Ah! Alors? Qu'il me fait comme ça... Ah! Tiens! Si je me retenais pas!... − Vas-y! que je lui dis... Je sens que ça monte* (Céline, *Mort à crédit*, 1936, p. 385).
[...]

---

TLFi, « [ça](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A7a) »

La chose, l'idée, les paroles que voilà. Abrév. fam. *ça*.
**I**.− GRAMMAIRE
[...]
**C**.− Loc. fam. cour. de la lang. parlée. [*Cela* est très souvent sous la forme *ça*]
[...]
**5**. *Comme cela*
**a**) Ainsi, de cette manière :
13. − Allons, voilà que tu vas te remettre à divaguer, dit Andrea, à parler et à reparler du passé toujours! Mais à quoi bon rabâcher *comme* **cela**, je te le demande? A. Dumas Père, *Le Comte de Monte-Cristo*, t. 2, 1846, p. 327.
− [Pour indiquer une mesure, hauteur, grandeur, largeur..., avec un geste de la main] *(Haut, grand, etc.) comme cela* :
14. ... j'ai laissé tomber mon outil et je me suis coupé l'artère du pied. Le sang a giclé haut *comme* **ça** (il montrait à une hauteur d'un mètre). Barrès, *Mes cahiers*, t. 7, 1908, p. 79.
− [Pour indiquer en partic. une très petite taille, en parlant d'une pers., d'un enfant] *Haut, grand comme cela, pas plus haut que cela.* Tout petit, de tout jeune, enfant. Synon. *haut comme trois pommes. Je l'appelle Maria, parce que je l'ai connue haute comme ça...* (Farrère, *L'Homme qui assassina*, 1907, p. 175).
− [Pour indiquer une grosse quantité] *Haut comme cela*. Beaucoup. *Elle en achète, des billets! Haut comme ça!* (Montherlant, *Fils de personne*, 1943, II, 1, p. 291).
− *Il (elle) est comme cela*. C'est son caractère, son comportement habituel. *Voilà, nous sommes comme ça, personne ne peut rien y faire* (Sartre, *L'Existentialisme est un humanisme*, 1946, p. 59).
− *C'est comme ça*. C'est ainsi fait, on ne peut rien y changer.
− [En fonction adj.] Synon. tel. *Mais c'est charmant, un domestique comme cela* (Balzac, Correspondance,1819, p. 30).
− Pop. [Pour indiquer un superl. : *très bien! extraordinaire!, avec un geste du pouce vers le haut*] *Un léger signe de lady Helena à son mari lui apprit que c'était « comme cela! »* (Verne, *Les Enfants du capitaine Grant*, t. 2, 1868, p. 8).

**b)** [Le sens de *comme ça* est plus atténué]
− [Le sens est précisé après coup par un ou plusieurs compl.] *− Où va-t-elle comme ça si vite, en robe du dimanche, un jour de semaine?* (Loti, *Pêcheur d'Islande*, 1886, p. 165).
− [Pour introduire une interr.] *Comme ça...?, alors comme ça...?* Ainsi donc...? *− Comme ça, vous ne vous plaisez pas au pays!* (Moselly, *Terres lorraines*, 1907, p. 45).
− Pop. *Il me dit, me fait comme ça.* *− Y a le chef qui a dit comme ça que vous alliez lui parler sitôt que vous seriez ici* (Courteline, *Messieurs-les-Ronds-de-cuir*, 1893, 1ertabl., 2, p. 31).
− [Pour donner une réponse vague, approximative] À peu près :
15. Un peu après, il m'a demandé : « C'est votre mère qui est là? » J'ai encore dit : « Oui. » « Elle était vieille? » J'ai répondu : « *Comme* **ça** », parce que je ne savais pas le chiffre exact. Camus, *L'Étranger*, 1942, p. 1134.
♦ Spéc. Pour répondre à une question sur sa santé (comment ça va?)
*Comme ça.* À peu près, pas trop bien. − Bien dormi? dit mon père. − Comme ça, répondis-je. J'ai trop bu de whisky hier soir (F. Sagan, Bonjour tristesse,1954, p. 65).
*Comme ci, comme ça* (*cf. couci-couça*). *Plutôt mal que bien. Jimmy (...) (à Manuel). − Angelica va bien? Manuel.

− Comme ci, comme ça. Enfin, elle va aussi bien que possible dans son état* (Bourdet, *Le Sexe faible*, 1931, I, p. 248).

---

LBU14 « Observations particulières sur cela et ça. / Emplois divers », §698 e 2 avec lien vers « explétion » (BDL) :

[...]
Dans la langue populaire, *comme ça* est souvent une formule [explétive](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4096) accompagnant un verbe : *Elle dit* COMME ÇA *que vous l'oubliez* [dit le père Rouault] (FLAUB., *Mme Bov.*, I, 3). — *Faut* COMME ÇA *de temps en temps que je boive un verre pour me donner des forces* (FRANCE, *Crainquebille*, p. 56).

---

LBU14 « Autres rôles de même », §647 c note R5 :

La loc. [*de même*] a aussi au Québec des emplois adverbiaux particuliers : *Il n'y a que Tit'Bé* [un garçon de 14 ans] *qui ait changé* [...]. *Quand vous avez quitté* [7 ans auparavant] *Mistassini il était haut* DE MÊME... »/Son geste indiquait la taille d'un enfant (HÉMON, *M. Chapdelaine*, III). Le sens n'est pas « de la même façon », mais « comme ça », geste à l'appui. Cf. Seutin-Clas, pp. 1550-1551.

Comment: Beaucoup de choses très vraies et des utilisations de « comme ça » qui ne sont pas un problème, qui sont claires et pas du tout la question, comme par exemple « Allons, voilà que tu vas te remettre à divaguer, dit Andrea, à parler et à reparler du passé toujours! Mais à quoi bon rabâcher comme cela, je te le demande? » ; l'antécédent est clair : « cela » est « je le dis, en divagations, en paroles et répétitions à propos du passé ». Cependant, la question est aussi abordée et la notion d'explétif selon LBU est essentielle ; elle est clairement formulée en connection avec « comme ça », (1/2)

Comment: ce qui va loin dans le sens d'établir que au moins dans certains cas il s'agirait bien d'une tournure pour laquelle la grammaire n'est d'aucun secours. Cela me montre que mon impression n'est pas un fait unique. Je ne considère pas votre recherche comme le mot final sur la question mais elle est largement suffisante pour  donner une inspiration solide en vue d'une résolution finale. (2/2)

Comment: « Mais à quoi bon rabâcher comme cela, je te le demande? », après qu'une personne ait dit quelque chose, c'est valide seul aussi pour _ainsi_. Le fait qu'on ait une explication, avant, après etc., n'est pas une condition de validité de la locution. Ce critère d'analyse t'éloigne du savoir à mon avis. Les sources présentées ici auraient dû se trouver dans ta question pour la préciser et mettre de côté ton inquiétude sur le registre, qui n'est pas fondée. En te concentrant uniquement sur ce qui est essentiel à la phrase, tu t'éloignes de la langue. Il n'est pas trop tard pour t'en convaincre.

Answer (score 2):

Il n'y a aucun tic de langage, aucun gallicisme, aucune faute de français, aucune « locution sans fondement grammatical », aucun « automatisme irraisonné », aucune tournure que « des gens avec un bon niveau d'instruction » éviteraient dans les quatre phrases citées en exemple:

> Mais arrête de mentir comme ça !
> Ne soit pas entêté comme ça, tu n'y gagnes rien…
> Ne vous mettez pas en colère comme ça !
> Pourquoi tu racontes ta vie à tout le monde comme ça ?

***Comme ça*** y signifie simplement « **de cette façon** », « **de cette manière** », « **comme tu le fais maintenant** », « **ainsi** » sans qu'il soit nécessaire de caractériser le mensonge, l'entêtement, la colère ou le manque de discrétion.

On retrouve exactement la même construction en anglais

> *Stop lying like that!*
> *Don't be stubborn like that,...*
> *Don't get upset like that!*
> *Why do you tell everyone about your life like that?*

Tu aurais pu trouver des exemples où *comme ça* n'a pas non plus d'antécédent implicite et où sa signification peut être alors « tranquillement », « moyennement », « médiocrement » suivant l'intonation :

> Ça s'est bien passé ton examen ?
> Ouais, comme ça.

[C sakom...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V04xN1AF5UE)

Comment: +1 pour le choix de la musique

Comment: C'est une explication qui est assez plausible mais si l'on va jusqu'au bout de ce raisonnement de construction de l'antécédent on a à considérer des équivalences telles que « Mais arrête de mentir de cette façon ! ». On s'attend tout de suite à la remarque du petit garçon espiègle : « Mais comment veux-tu que je mentes Maman ? ». Je pense que ce n'est pas très convainquant.

Comment: Personne n'a aucune chance de te convaincre puisque ta question montre bien que ton opinion est déjà faite.